# C# images cropping,splitting,saving

Tags: c#, image, crop, save, split

as stated in subject, i have an image:

```
    private Image testing;
    testing = new Bitmap(@"sampleimg.jpg");
```

I would like to split it into 3 x 3 matrix meaning 9 images in total and save it.Any tips or tricks to do this simple? I'm using visual studios 2008 and working on smart devices. Tried some ways but i can't get it. This is what i tried:

```
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int width = 3;
        int height = 3;


        int count = testing.Width / width;
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);


        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);


        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
            g.DrawImage(testing, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            bmp.Save(Path.ChangeExtension(@"C\AndrewPictures\", String.Format(".{0}.bmp",i)));
            x += width;
        }
```

Comment: i tried this too : 

string path = @"C\AndrewPictures";

bmp.Save(Path.ChangeExtension(path, String.Format(".{0}.bmp",i)));

but i get 
Error 1 No overload for method 'Save' takes '1' arguments

Answer (score 10):

Depending on the .NET version, you could do one of the following to crop:

[.NET 2.0](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing)

```
private static Image cropImage(Image img, Rectangle cropArea)
{
   Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(img);
   Bitmap bmpCrop = bmpImage.Clone(cropArea,
   bmpImage.PixelFormat);
   return (Image)(bmpCrop);
}
```

Or **[.NET 3.5+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752345.aspx)**

```
// Create an Image element.
Image croppedImage = new Image();
croppedImage.Width = 200;
croppedImage.Margin = new Thickness(5);

// Create a CroppedBitmap based off of a xaml defined resource.
CroppedBitmap cb = new CroppedBitmap(     
   (BitmapSource)this.Resources["masterImage"],
   new Int32Rect(30, 20, 105, 50));       //select region rect
croppedImage.Source = cb;                 //set image source to cropped
```

As you can see, it's a bit more simple than what you're doing. The first example clones the current image and takes a subset of it; the second example uses `CroppedBitmap`, which supports taking a section of the image right from the constructor.

The splitting part is simple maths, just splitting the image into 9 sets of coordinates and passing them into the constructor.

Comment: +1 for cropping via Bitmap.Clone, it's what I'm using to extract small regions out of images for ROI display and it works well.

Comment: yes i've gone to this website http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing

I think i'll stick to my method, just that i can't save the images...

Comment: And by croppedImage.Margin = new Thickness(5); does it means height? i do not have the method, am i missing some reference?