# Cropping multiple images and resizing them in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, crop

I have made a website in which i needed to upload multiple images like below image.
[image]

The 1,2,3,4 and 5(in red) are 5 different images which are uploaded and resized.Now i have to crop the whole 5 images considering as a single image. I need the output like this.

[image]

Also i should be able to resize that cropped image later.

Comment: i dont know how to proceed  with multiple image cropping.Can you provide me any examples?

Comment: Maybe this helps a little http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894835/c-sharp-images-cropping-splitting-saving

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6620/ASP-NET-Image-Manipulation-Examples-Adding-Zooming

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to draw all the images onto the same Bitmap instance, then you can crop the resulting bitmap.

Most importantly, NEVER, EVER use ANY CLASS in the System.Drawing namespace unless you put it in a using(){} clause. They are NOT garbage collected - at least not quickly enough to prevent your server from crashing.

[Something else you should read](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/).